# Ubuntu with ZOL and LUKS

Tags: encryption, luks, zfs, cryptsetup

I'm trying to install ZOL with LUKS and I'm not entirely sure how to proceed. I've plenty of material on how to get ZOL installed to the root of my target media. However, there's not much on getting ZOL working in combination with LUKS.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

ZFS on Linux doesn't offer builtin encryption. What you can do is use LUKS encrypted volumes as disks in a ZFS pool.

The DMCrypt kernel module in Linux provides block device level encryption and LUKS makes it easy to setup and manage the keys, with the `cryptsetup` tool.

You basically layer ZFS on top of DMCrypt, so everything ZFS writes to disk will actually be encrypted on the fly. Same thing when ZFS reads, data will be read from disk, unencrypted and passed to ZFS. You should still get everything ZFS has to offer in terms of volume management and all the rest, only on top of encrypted volumes. Sounds good, but:

- I'm not entirely sure about performance. Maybe it's not too bad, if your CPU has support for encryption.
- Also, I think maintenance will be harder. In case a disk breaks, ZFS will let you know the pool is in *faulted* status and you will need to replace the drive. Before you can attach the new drive to the pool, you will have to setup the encryption for that particular drive.

I have to say (and I'm aware you didn't ask, but I think is relevant) I'm not a big fan of online/mounted encrypted volumes on hard drives, because the encryption will actually protect data only when the drives get unmounted and detached from the system. As long as the system is on and the encrypted partition is mounted, data is available *unencrypted*. I think there is a compromise to make here: encrypted, more secure data, in exchange for lower performance and harder maintenance. Now, if you fear someone could take your disks away from you, maybe you have a good use case for ZFS over LUKS.

I normally use LUKS for removable media and I don't use ZFS on usb drives, so the compromise is easier to make in that case.

I have personally never used LUKS in combination with ZFS, but others did. For example, you could take a look at this article for some inspiration: [Encrypted ZFS with Ubuntu](http://www.larsko.org/ZfsUbuntu).